# Delete files with special characters in filenames in linux

Tags: linux

I've accidentally created files with names that won't allow me to delete them:

```
-d
--header
```

Doing the following has no effect:

```
rm -f '-d'
rm -f '--header'
unlink ('-d');
unlink ('--archive');
```

Unlink gives an error:

```
unlink: invalid option -- 'd'
Try 'unlink --help' for more information.
```

How can I get rid of these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `--` to tell BASH that the *command options* has ended, then, all other parameters are treated as *positional parameters* so they wont be interpreted by `rm`;

```sh
rm -- --header
rm -- --d
```

[Screenshot of example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ErxQq.png)

More on `--`: [What does “--” (double-dash) mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean)

Comment: Thank you! That was a huge help.